# Update dynamically generated list item (generated using PHP) after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

The following HTML code is being **`echo`ed** using a while loop in PHP which is adding a list item after fetching data from database.

**PHP:**

```
echo '
<li>

  <div class="collapsible-header">

    <div class = "left">
      <div class = "issueStatusIcon" style = "background-color:'.$smallCircleColor.';">'.$smallMsg.'</div>
      <span class = "issueTitle" style = "font-family: robotoBold">'.$issueTitle.'</span>
    </div>

    <div class = "issueButtonsGroup">
      <form id = "archiveIssueForm'.$i.'" issue-name = "'.$issueTitle.'" action = "archiveIssue.php">
        <input type = "hidden" value = "'.$issueID.'" name = "issueID"/>
      </form>
      <a class = "right archiveIconButton" onclick = "ajaxIssueArchive('.$i.')" href = "#">
          <i class="material-icons black-text issueOptions archiveIcon">archive</i>
      </a>
      <a class = "right"><i class="material-icons black-text issueOptions">edit</i></a>
    </div>

  </div>                          

</li>                  
';
```

**This is the preview image of the generated list:**
[image: preview image]

Notice the cursor over the *archive button* which archives the list item. The `class` for that button is `archiveIconButton` *(you can find it in the above code)*. When the button is clicked, `archiveIssueForm` is submitted via AJAX (each form has a unique identifier variable `$i` appended to its id).

Following is the JQuery AJAX code:

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
  function ajaxIssueArchive($num){

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "archiveIssue.php",
      data: $('#archiveIssueForm' + $num).serialize(),

      success: function(data){

        $fetchIssueName = $('#archiveIssueForm' + $num).attr("issue-name");
        $toastText = $fetchIssueName + " has been archived";
        Materialize.toast($toastText, 3000);
        $('#archiveIssueForm' + $num).html(data);
      }
    });

  }
</script>
```

After archiving any list item, it gets deleted from the database. I want to update the `ul` element which contains these list items so that the list item which gets deleted doesn't gets displayed after the AJAX form submission.

Assume the id of ul to be `issueListUL`.

What i'm currently getting is the whole code of the html page displayed in the li item. I am certainly doing something wrong, any help would be appreciated!

**After archiving a list item:**
[image: preview image 2]

Comment: What is response code returned on ajax called?

Comment: It is `data`. I have serialized archiveIssueForm @stweb

Comment: This sounds like the form is being submitted and since it has no action attribute it simply reloads the page and that content gets inserted into the list. Guess you should set the action of the form and stop event propagation of the submit event. Also set the href attribute of your link to simply '#' or similar. The rest of your code looks fine...

Comment: @Kjell I tried what you said, i added the `action` attribute and i added `href = '#'` to the button. It didn't work, its still showing up the same div i.e the same dashboard in the list item(as shown in the 2nd image) after ajax call. I've updated the code in my question too!

Comment: Add  console.log(data); inside success function and post the result displayed in console of your browser here for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: @stweb The whole html page's code is being displayed in the log.

Comment: My idea - archiveIssue.php is not found, To check it put simple output inside archiveIssue.php and return. For ex. echo 'test'; return; at the begining.

Comment: @stweb The form is getting submitted. If i refresh the page, the list gets updated appropriately. But still to be sure i'll what you're saying. PS:The echo is working. **image with echo text in it**: http://i.imgur.com/7Sf9Fix.png **image with code**: http://i.imgur.com/QURN0Hw.png

Comment: The code you provided returns the whole table, and you are inserting data in a part of table - #archiveIssueForm. You need to create one php for output whole table and another for the archive action. Or change the selector here  $('#archiveIssueForm' + $num).html(data); to the selector of table container.

Comment: @stweb My question is that why the whole html is being passed as `data` when i'm just serializing the form?

Comment: yep, the whole code returned by your script gets inserted at the given point.

Comment: your archive script could also simply return TRUE or FALSE depending on the success of archiving. Then you simply remove the LI from your list...

Comment: @Kjell That's a front end solution, i thought of that but isn't there a way to just refresh the list container?

Comment: Fully agree with Kjell. You need to change selector in your jQuery to update all table and not only archive part of item or remove li element.

Comment: @stweb assume the id of the `<ul>` which contains the list to be `listContainer`, how would you proceed?

Comment: Put the <ul id="items">... and change selector in jquery from  $('#archiveIssueForm' + $num).html(data); to  $('#items').html(data);

Comment: @stweb Ok, i got it. The problem is that the data contains the **whole html code** (i.e. HTML + jquery script everything) here is the console log of the data being displayed: http://i.imgur.com/IzcxsQA.png (More code is there below)

Comment: To perform single action with ajax you need to have separate php file that process your ajax requests only.

Comment: And if your task is remove archived item, do as Kjell said - remove it in jquery code.

Comment: @stweb Is there some way to select some particular div from the `data` which is there since it's the whole html code? http://i.imgur.com/XWRkkMB.png -> this is the container which contains all the list items PS> that's the screenshot of data being displayed in the console.log()

Comment: You can parse data. But I don't recomend this cause it's hard and wrong way.

Comment: @stweb Ok! Got it :D Thankyou so much! Post an answer if you can so that i can accept it and give you credit! :D Cheers

Comment: @Kjell Thankyou so much! Post an answer if you can so that i can accept it and give you credit! :D Cheers!

Comment: The answer is in comments ), and they can be rated also.

Comment: @stweb Actually, i found a way to do it by extracting the ul's html content from `data` and replacing the html of the existing `ul` with updated `ul`'s html ! I'll post an answer for this.

Comment: Yes, of course you can send HTML stuff back and forth and parse it and have the same result, but it's not required. A done or cannot be done status from the server is fairly sufficient and much less error prone... Great that we were able to help u!

Comment: @Kjell Actually i have different tabs loaded in the same html page, i'm just enabling and disabling their views using jQuery, im not using different html pages for these tabs. This list is being displayed at 2 different places. So whenever the user selects the other tab which is displaying this list, the issue which was deleted would still be displayed over there. So a front end fix was not the optimal solution for me. That's why i was eager to find a way to do it using ajax. Again thanks for all your help mate :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue in the following way, The JQuery script in the question should be changed like this:

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
  function ajaxIssueArchive($num){

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: "archiveIssue.php",
      data: $('#archiveIssueForm' + $num).serialize(),

      success: function(data){

        //assigning the updated ul's html to a variable
        $afterIssueArchival = $(data).find("#issueListContainer").html();

        //toast
        $fetchIssueName = $('#archiveIssueForm' + $num).attr("issue-name");
        $toastText = $fetchIssueName + " has been archived";
        Materialize.toast($toastText, 3000);

        //updation of ul's html, ID of the ul which contains all the list items is assumed to be 'listContainer'

        $("#issueListContainer").html($afterIssueArchival);
      }
    });

  }
</script>
```

When updating an element's html, **just extract the element's updated html code from `data` attribute in the ajax code** *(as show in the above code)* **and update the existing element's html with it**!

Hope this helps people with the same problem as mine! :D